# Does 'be off' meaning 'leave/go away' in the past tense?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I made up the following situation:

> There are 3 friends named A, B and C.
> One day A says to B: "I am off to Africa next week."
> A couple of days later B says to C: "C, I met A the other day. She told me she was off to Africa this week."

Is what B says correct? Does "was off" make sense and still have to do with "leave"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it still makes sense. There is no reason why **be off to** would change its basic meaning, just because the speaker (and so grammatical person) or tense has changed.

The **was** is fine, following standard tense backshifting used with indirect reported speech. However, as you may know, backshift is sometimes seen as optional, particularly in less formal English. So you could also substitute **is** for **was**.

Comment: Are "He asked her when she was off to Africa?" and "He asked her when she would be off to Africa?" correct?

Comment: Yes. If backshifting is followed, the latter suggests that the real-life question asked was "when will you be off to Africa"?